# How can I get an AngularJS without using the debug mode?

Tags: angularjs, console, angularjs-scope

I know I can enable `$compileProvider` to see debug info, but in my case, I prefer not to enable it.

When I use `angular.element($0).scope();` or `$($0).data().$scope`
it is returning undefined. I wonder if there is any solution that doesn't need to turn on debug info to get `$scope` with jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs scope variables in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799494/angularjs-scope-variables-in-console)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **select the element** from developer mode then go with console in browser.:
Before this it must be ensure that your angularjs library loaded.

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$0` is a reference to the select element of the DOM.  You probably gets `undefined` because you didn't select an element of the DOM before asking for its scope.

There is [two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-do-i-access-the-scope-variable-in-browsers-console-using-angularjs) to do it:

- <kbd>Right click</kbd> + <kbd>inspect</kbd> an element, then run `angular.element($0).scope();`
- Get the element from its ID directly in the console: `angular.element(document.getElementById('elementId')).scope();`